# OCaml Signature with multiple types

Tags: ocaml, functor

I would like to represent some scalar value (e.g. integers or strings)
by either it's real value or by some `NA` value and later store them
in a collection (e.g. a list). The purpose is to handle missing values.

To do this, I have implemented a signature

```
module type Scalar = sig
    type t
    type v = Value of t | NA
end
```

Now I have some polymorphic `Vector` type in mind that contains `Scalar`s. Basically, some of the following

```
module Make_vector(S: Scalar) = struct
    type t = S.v list

    ... rest of the functor ...
end
```

However, I cannot get this to work. I would like to do something like

```
module Int_vector = Make_vector(
    struct
        type t = int
    end
)

module Str_vector = Make_vector(
    struct
        type t = string
    end
)

... and so on for some types.
```

I have not yet worked a lot with OCaml so maybe this is not the right way. Any advises on how to realize such a polymorphic Scalar with a sum type?

The compiler always responds with the following message:

```
The parameter cannot be eliminated in the result type. 
Please bind the argument to a module identifier.
```

Before, I have tried to implement `Scalar` as a sum type but ran into 
complexity issues when realizing some features due to huge `match` clauses. Another (imo not so nice) option would be to use `option`. Is this a better strategy?

Answer (score 0):

As far as I can see, you are structuring `v` as an input type to your functor, but you really want it to be an output type. Then when you apply the functor, you supply only the type `t` but not `v`. My suggestion is to move the definition of `v` into your implementation of `Make_vector`.

Answer (score 0):

What are you trying to do exactly with modules / functors? Why simple `'a option list` is not good enough? You can have functions operating on it, e.g.

```ml
let rec count_missing ?acc:(acc=0) = function
    | None::tail -> count_missing ~acc:(acc+1) tail
    | _::tail -> count_missing ~acc tail
    | [] -> acc ;;


val count_missing : ?acc:int -> 'a option list -> int = <fun>

count_missing [None; Some 1; None; Some 2] ;;
- : int = 2

count_missing [Some "foo"; None; Some "bar"] ;;
- : int = 1
```